# Can't remotely connect to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, rhel, postgresql-9.6

I have followed all the advice I've found online, but I can't seem to get this to work.

**Background:**

I have setup Postgresql 9.6 on a server running RHEL 6.8. I am trying to remotely connect to this server's Postgresql service from a client running Linux Mint 17.3.

**What I've tried:**

1) In postgresql.conf, I added these two lines:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

2) In pg_hba.conf, I added this line:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

3) Restarted postgresql server afterwards:

```
service postgresql-9.6 restart
```

4) Added rule to firewall to allow connections to port 5432 just in case:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

5) Ran `netstat -tulpn | grep 5432` and got this output:

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5432 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2625/postmaster
tcp 0 0 ::::5432     :::*      LISTEN 2625/postmaster
```

Here is the command I ran to connect to my server from the client:

```
psql -h my_host_name -d my_database_name -U postgres
```

And I got the following output:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "my_host_name" (my_ip_address) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**Question**:

What else can I do to further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Does `psql -h 127.0.0.1 ...` work from RHEL?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was another firewall on our network that I wasn't taking into account. To anybody else dealing with this issue, make sure that you are *absolutely* sure that you are not dealing with a firewall.